# Let $S = \{a,b\}$. Write down a table that defines a binary operation $*$ on $S$ such that $(S,*)$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that your table works..

What I'm confused about is what my table should look like in order to prove that it is associative.

Comment: Either $a$ is the identity or $b$ is, right? Combined with the fact that every element has an inverse, this gives you only two possible groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some additional help: in a group if $x\ast x = x$, then $x$ must be the (unique) identity. Also, $a\ast a$ and $a\ast b$ must be distinct, since otherwise:

$a = (e \ast a) = (a^{-1} \ast a) \ast a = a^{-1}\ast(a \ast a) = a^{-1}\ast(a\ast b) = (a^{-1} \ast a) \ast b = e\ast b = b$.

Similarly, $a \ast b$ and $b \ast b$ cannot be the same element.

So, if for example, you chose $e = a$, the only product undetermined is $b \ast b$, and since $a \ast b = b$ (for this choice of identity), it MUST BE that $b \ast b = a$.

The all you have to do is verify associativity for your multiplication table, which only involves 8 checks:

$a\ast(a\ast a) = (a\ast a)\ast a\\a\ast(a\ast b) = (a\ast a)\ast b\\a\ast(b\ast a) = (a\ast b)\ast a\\b\ast(a\ast a) = (b\ast a)\ast a\\b\ast(b\ast a) = (b\ast b)\ast a\\b\ast(a\ast b) = (b\ast a)\ast b\\a\ast(b\ast b) = (a\ast b)\ast b\\b\ast(b\ast b) = (b\ast b)\ast b$.

This may seem daunting, but actually performing it is easier than it looks (see Hagen's answer above).

Comment: Thank you so much! All other tables we worked with had more than two elements. I realize now that I was just way overthinking this one.

Answer (score 0):

Verification odf associativity is not a problem: Note that when testing $$\tag1x*(y*z)\stackrel?= (x*y)*z$$ either at least one of $x,y,z$ is the neutral element (and you already set up your table such that it *is* neutral) and then $(1)$ is clear. Or $x=y=z\ne 1$ and then for this single instance  $(1)$ can be checked readily (and is in fact again unavoidable)